# Missing Back-Button on DateTimeElement (Monotouch.Dialog)

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, monotouch.dialog

I use this simple piece of code for my UI:

```
challengeStartTime = new DateTimeElement("Start Time",DateTime.Now);

Root = new RootElement ("Add Event") {
    new Section (""){
        challengeStartTime
    }
};
```

I use this code for a while, everything worked as expected. Now I migrate the app to iOS 7 and this strange behaviour appears: 1. Navigate to the DateTimeElement 2. Navigate back to the previous screen (there is the usual Back-Button in the NavigationController-Bar) 3. Navigate again to the DateTimeElement (e.g. if I entered the wrong time) 4. There is NO back button in the NavigationController. No way to navigate back.

I verified my old version again (Appstore, "win4youth") and there it works without problems.

Any ideas what could cause this strange issue? I already downloaded the current version of https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog, compiled and tried it, but the same behaviour. I'm using a storyboard for the other screens, maybe it's related to that?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Check if somewhere in your code you are hiding the back button of the navigation controller. Either `SetHidesBackButton` or `HidesBackButton`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Krumelur for pointing out the right direction!

I had this code in my DialogViewController:

```
public override void ViewDidAppear (bool animated)
{
    //this "hack" is necessary because we use a DialogViewController together with a Storyboard and have no control over the constructor
    this.NavigationItem.HidesBackButton = false;

    base.ViewDidAppear (animated);
}
```

Which seems to cause the problem. Strangely,  before iOS 7 it was working. After a little research I found this thread: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/8291/navigationcontroller-missing-back-button-when-coming-from-the-third-level-to-the-second-level

Which provided me a solution:

```
public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear (animated);

    NavigationItem.SetHidesBackButton (false, false);
}

public override void ViewWillDisappear (bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillDisappear (animated);

    NavigationItem.SetHidesBackButton (true, false);
}
```

It's still a hack, but at least a working one :-)